# How can I prevent this loop from printing something in my array when it encounters an error condition?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, error-checking

I'm writing a placeShips method for the game Battleship. It works for the most part... except when I'm trying to place a ship, and it encounters an error condition (goes off the board, another ship in that location, etc) it'll print the ship's character code in the space right up until it realizes it shouldn't. I've tried to use a cascaded if statement and I'm not sure how else to solve this problem. Here's a snippet of the code. There are five different ships, but this is the code for just the placement of the first one in a 10x10 array with all characters initialized to ~.

```
int count=1;
while(count<=5){
    start: {
    if(count==1){
    System.out.println("What row and column would you like to place your aircraft carrier?");
    System.out.println("Row?");
    int row1 = IO.readInt();
                    if(row1>9 || row1<0){
                    IO.reportBadInput();
                    break start;
                    }
    System.out.println("Column?");
    int column1 = IO.readInt();
                    if(column1>9 || column1<0){
                    IO.reportBadInput();
                    break start;
                    }

    System.out.println("How would you like to orient your aircraft carrier? 1. Down, 2. Up, 3. Left, 4. Right");
    int orientation = IO.readInt();
    if(orientation==1){ //oriented down

        for(int z=0; z<5; z++){ //places the aircraft carrier, DOWN
        if((row1+z)>=board.length){
            System.out.println("This will go off the board. You can't place your ship here! Try again.");
            IO.reportBadInput();
            break start;
        }

        else if(board[row1+z][column1]!='~'){
            System.out.println("Oops! You can't place your ship there. Ship already in this location. Try again.");
            IO.reportBadInput();
            break start;
        } //checks if there's anything else already in that space

        else{
            board[row1 + z][column1]= 'A';
        } 

        } 
    }
        if(orientation==2){ //oriented up

            for(int z=0; z<5; z++){ //places the aircraft carrier, UP ORIENTATION
            if((row1-z)<0){
                System.out.println("This will go off the board. You can't place your ship here! Try again.");
                IO.reportBadInput();
                break start;
            }
            else if(board[row1-z][column1]!='~'){
                System.out.println("Oops! You can't place your ship there. Ship already in this location. Try again.");
                IO.reportBadInput();
                break start;
            } //checks if there's anything else already in that space
            else{
                board[row1 - z][column1]= 'A';
            }

            }
        }

            if(orientation==3){

                for(int z=0; z<5; z++){ //places the aircraft carrier, LEFT ORIENTATION
                if((column1-z)<0){
                    System.out.println("This will go off the board. You can't place your ship here! Try again.");
                    IO.reportBadInput();
                    break start;
                }
                else if(board[row1][column1-z]!='~'){
                    System.out.println("Oops! You can't place your ship there. Ship already in this location. Try again.");
                    IO.reportBadInput();
                    break start;
                } //checks if there's anything else already in that space
                else{
                    board[row1][column1-z]= 'A'; 
                }

                }
            }


            if(orientation==4){

                for(int z=0; z<5; z++){ //places the aircraft carrier, RIGHT ORIENTATION
                if((column1+z)>=9){
                    System.out.println("This will go off the board. You can't place your ship here! Try again.");
                    IO.reportBadInput();
                    break start;
                }
                else if(board[row1][column1+z]!='~'){
                    System.out.println("Oops! You can't place your ship there. Ship already in this location. Try again.");
                    IO.reportBadInput();
                    break start;
                } //checks if there's anything else already in that space
                else{
                    board[row1][column1+z]= 'A';
                }

                }
}
    count++;
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend that you use boolean methods to separate your tests from your code; e.g a method that takes `shipSize` and `orientation` and checks that both (row, col) and the final location (which varies depending on orientation) exist. If they both return true, it'll be true. So if the method is `isValidPlacement(int shipSize, int orientation)`, you would call `if(isValidPlacement(5, 1))` for an aircraft carrier facing downward.

Comment: Precisely what error condition? Have you attempted to use a debugger?

Comment: My error conditions are as follows: The ship cannot go off the board, so if the user picks a row or column greater than 9 or less than 0 that is an error condition. If they pick a valid coordinate but the ship goes off the board (each ship is more than one space), that is an error condition. If there is already a ship in that location, that is an error condition.